# How can I address performance issues in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, performance, virtual-reality, aframe

I have the following scene:

[image: Measuring Amperes Scene]

There are a bunch of spheres moving 0.5 to the right, indefinitely. All the spheres are under a parent object, whose animation is applied to. At the very beginning there's a noticeable lag. After about 2 minutes, everything moves really fast.

I'm using Firefox Nightly Version 56.a1, Oculus Rift+Touch Windows 10, GTX 1060,  i7 4820K.

What are the things that I must watch out for? Any recommendations? I've seen more complex games (All shown in the Aframe.io website) achieve better performance, so there's definitely a trick for it. I also realize AFrame isn't yet in production. Any resources I cold go into?

Comment: You can add `stats` attribute to the `<a-scene>` tag to monitor the stats, you can observe if you have too many vertices and faces in your scene. Don't new objects in the frame loop, or it would cost much time to collect the garbage, just define it outside and reuse it.

Comment: @Craig.Li: Thanks :). I've replaced the Spheres for the particle system, and it's a little bit  better ;). But that doesn't solve it completely. Thanks for the stats attribute. 

Could you better explain "Don't new objects in the frame loop?"

Comment: You know the scene always has a 60 FPS(frame per second), that's mean the scene would be rendered 60 times, In A-Frame, the tick function of A-Frame component would be executed 60 times, if you create instance in every frame loop, the js engine would recycle these instances, and lead to a lower performance. So, create a single instance, and reuse it.

Comment: @Craig.Li Oooh I see. Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out! We've also discovered that there was a problem with how raycasters work. This answer solved it (Apparently): https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/aframe/10036/raycasters-component/30809/whitelisting-entities-to-test-for-intersection#t=201707102003359736153